# Как получить строку, содержащую переменные и другие строки без использования двойных или одинарных кавычек и операторов +

Tags: javascript

```js
function Fucn () {
    var userName = 'Sam';
    var heightUserName = 187;
    
    alert(userName + '`s height: ' + heightUserName);
}

Fucn();
```

Comment: каких из 4-х кавычек в Вашем коде, Вы хотите, чтобы не было?

Comment: в алерте не видно кавычек? '`s height: '

Comment: в алерте не видно кавычек. в алерте видeн апостроф.

Comment: какой апостроф? это одинарные кавычки

Comment: Так где кавычек быть не должно ? в присвоении переменной userName надо то же без них ? и в алерте, фиксированный текст то же должен быть без них ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В новом стандарте есть фича под названием обратные кавычки, реализация примерно следующая:

```js
function Fucn () {
    let userName = 'Sam';
    let heightUserName = 187;

    alert(`${userName} \`s height: ${heightUserName}`);
}

Fucn();
```